# Order dependent pgfkeys

Tags: pgfkeys

**Short question**

How can I set the value of a key depending on the last used keys, by modifying only `\pgfkeys` ?

**Long question**

I'd like to define a set of pgfkeys that then I will be able to use in lots of functions. I'd like the have only a few number of parameters, like, for example "width","height" and "pos", so that my functions are then very easy to use. So the basic idea would be to use:

```
\myRectangle[width=1cm, height=2cm, pos={(current page.center)}}
```

However, I'd like to allow the user the capability of using shortcuts. For example, if he uses the key `fullWidth`, the it's exactly the same thing as using `width=\pagewidth`:

```
\myRectangle[fullWidth, height=2cm, pos={(current page.center)}}
```

but because the rectangle fills  the whole width, it's useless to give two values for the position, only 1 is useful (the height here). So I'd like to be able to let the user use:

```
\myRectangle[fullWidth, height=2cm, pourcent=.5}
```

in place of

```
\myRectangle[fullWidth, height=2cm, pos={(current page.north east) + (current page.north west) + (0,-.5\paperheight)}}
```

and if we just replace `fullWidth` with `fullHeight`, then the code

```
\myRectangle[fullWidth, height=2cm, pourcent=.5}
```

should be equivalent to

```
\myRectangle[fullWidth, height=2cm, pos={(current page.north east) + (current page.north west) + (.5\paperheight,0)}}
```

(Notice that now, the last pair has changed)

So, as you saw, `pourcent` has two different goals, depending on the last used keys, and I don't know how to express that in the code.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\graphicspath{{photos/}} % on change la racine

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
% Define the used keys in the following document
\pgfkeys{
  /myKeys/.is family, /myKeys,
  default/.style =
  {
    width  = 1cm,
    height = 1cm,
    pos = {(current page.center)},
  },
  width/.estore in = \kWidth,
  height/.estore in = \kHeight,
  pos/.estore in = \kPos,
  % Non fundamental keys
  fullWidth/.style = {width=\paperwidth},
  fullHeight/.style = {height=\paperheight},
  pourcent/.style args={#1}{
    % Works for fullWidth...
    pos={(current page.north west) + (.5\paperwidth,-#1\paperheight)}
    % But for fullHeight it should be
    % pos={(current page.north west) + (#1\paperwidth,-.5\paperheight)}
  }
}

% Create a rectangle. You can set the properties color, width
% height, pos, anchor, fullWidth, fullHeight, pospc, background
\newcommand{\myRectangle}[1][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/myKeys, default, #1}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \node [inner sep=0pt, shape=rectangle, fill=red, minimum width=\kWidth, minimum height=\kHeight, anchor=center, at/.expanded={($\kPos$)}] {};%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\myRectangle[fullWidth,pos={(current page.center)}]

\myRectangle[fullWidth,pourcent=.7]

% Does not work as expected... see pourcent/.style
\myRectangle[fullHeight,pourcent=.9]

\end{document}
```

-- EDIT --
I tried:

```
  pourcent/.code args={#1}{
    \edef\w{\pgfkeysvalueof{pourcent}}%
    \ifx\w\paperwidth\relax%
    \pgfkeysalso{pos={(current page.north west) + (.5\paperwidth,-#1\paperheight)}}%
    \else%
    \pgfkeysalso{pos={(current page.north west) + (.5\paperwidth,-\paperheight)}}%
    \fi%
  },
```

it compiles, but does not work, I guess that the expression `\edef\w{\pgfkeysvalueof{pourcent}}` does not reduce...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got it !!!

```
  pourcent/.code args={#1}{
    \ifdim\kWidth=\paperwidth\relax%
    \pgfkeysalso{pos={(current page.north west) + (.5\paperwidth,-#1\paperheight)}}%
    \else\ifdim\kHeight=\paperheight\relax%
    \pgfkeysalso{pos={(current page.north west) + (#1\paperwidth,-.5\paperheight)}}%
    \else\fi\fi%
  },
```